# Is it possible to dual boot two instances of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I've been programming for about a year and I'm very new to Ubuntu. I'm currently working on a project with a mentor who suggested partitioning part of my drive with a fresh Ubuntu install. I've never done anything like this and most of the guides I've seen are for dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows/MacOS.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I was wondering If I could keep my current setup and also partition part of my drive with a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI be sure to also back up the ESP - efi system partition first. Second install will overwrite /EFI/ubuntu. That still should work, but if you want first install in control of booting you need to restore backup, or manually edit grub.cfg in ESP. I typically use another 25GB for each / (root) including /home, but have almost all data in separate data partition I use for all Ubuntu installs. The /home  then can be configurated differently if you want as it is just user settings.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! When you get to the section on setting up your disks during installation, choose the option to install alongside the existing Ubuntu installation. If you're interested in setting up with more detailed partitioning, comment on this question and I'll edit this post.